# function validating numeric values used with conditional

Tags: bash, function

I have a function that validates numeric values, and want to use it in `if` statements.

```
num=3
if numeric -I "$num"
then
  printf '%s\n' "$num is numeric integer" 
fi
```

Is there a way to group `numeric -I "$num"` together as is done with `[]`, `[[]]`, and `(())`?

Comment: This is exactly the way to do it: if the function returns with exit status zero (success), then the printf statement is executed.

Comment: Note the [documentation for `if`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-if) -- **commands** follow `if`. That implies that `[` and `[[` and `((` are _commands_ (or shell keywords, to be technical)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> group `numeric -I "$num"` together as is done with `[]`, `[[]]`, and `(())`.

The main purpose of `[ ]`, `[[ ]]` or `(( ))` is to do different things to what's inside, not to group. You can group commands using `{ }`; grouping exactly one command this way is allowed. You can run command(s) in a subshell using `( )`, in this case there's little difference.

So `if { numeric -I "$num"; }` or `if (numeric -I "$num")` should work. Completely unnecessary, but if this is what you want…

Comment: Would this be valid as well ? `[[ numeric -I "$num" ]] && printf '%s\n' "numeric"`

Comment: @Aardvark No. `[[` will *not* interpret `numeric` as something to run. See the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs), `[[` is described there, its purpose is different. `numeric -I "$num" && printf '%s\n' "numeric"` is valid; if you want the first part to stand out *visually* in the code, use `{ }` like in the answer.